# Trouble getting meta description from some sites using php

Tags: php, regex, meta-tags

I cannot fetch the meta description tag from some sites, one in particular is you-tube.

I have tried using "get_meta_tags" however it does not return the description. I have tried using several regex as well. The title returns fine.

Try getting the description from this link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xci0-26M-bk

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xci0-26M-bk';
if ($fp = @fopen($url, 'r')) {
    $file = file($url);
    $file = implode("", $file);
    $tags = get_meta_tags($url);
    $description = trim($tags['description']);
}
```

$description returns blank...

Comment: why could you not just post the youtube url?

Comment: Wasn't sure if links were allowed

Comment: If you create (and paste) a sample PHP file and show the output you get (and what you expect to get), it would be easier to analyze the problem.

Comment: Can you do a `print_r($tags);`?

Comment: Hey I found the problem, setting the user_agent to a generic mozilla string was not getting the tags. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put directly the $url in get_meta_tags?

If I do:

```
print_r(get_meta_tags('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xci0-26M-bk'));
```

I get:

```
Array ( [title] => Catfish Blues - Jimi Hendrix Experience [description] => Couldn&#39;t ignore Jimi any longer. This is a track recorded for Radio one about 1967. Love the simplicity (seemingly)and the, understated, power. [keywords] => Jimi, Hendrix, sixties )
```

Comment: Hey I found the problem it was due to the browser agent. However I am having trouble passing the description through javascript I keep getting unterminated string error...pass("<? echo addslashes($description) ?>"); JS or php is converting the single quote to &#39; and it causes problems

Comment: It's not converting it, it's like this on youtube!

Comment: I can convert the &#39; to a ' but when I pass it to JS it gets converted back to &#39;

Comment: Hey, the html_entity_decode "ENT_QUOTES" was causing the conversion. Thanks for you help.